# Sending a JQuery variable on post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

Can't get my head around this Jquery problem I have..
I've been looking around and found some solutions but they don't seem to work.

I have a MVC project and in one view I am using sortable and that works like a charm.
The problem is when I want to send the new order of my list back to the controller..
I'm using `alert(items)` and it shows me the string I want..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ArrangeAttributesViewModel</legend>
        <div id="contentWrap">
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            <div>
                _category.CategoryName</div>
            <div id="attributeList" class="container">
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var _category in Model.AttributeList)
                    {
                        <li id="@("a_" + _category.CategoryID.ToString())">
                            @_category.CategoryName
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" id="SaveButton" value="Save Changes" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li").hover(function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'move');
            $(this).css('background-color', '#2c87b2');
        },
            function () {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
                $(this).css('background-color', '#5c87b2');
            });

        $("#attributeList ul").sortable({
            opacity: 0.6,
            cursor: 'move',
            update: function () {
                items = $(this).sortable('toArray');
                alert(items);
            }
        });

        var items;

        $("#SaveButton").click(function () {
            alert(items);

            $.post({
                url: '/Profile/ArrangeCategories',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { items: items },
                traditional: true
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I'm using

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize]
public ActionResult ArrangeCategories(int ProfileID, string[] items)
```

in the controller..

Any help much appreciated!

Edit:
I've changed the code a bit after some user input..

Now everything works fine up until the sending of the variable, in other words I see the alert when I press the button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved the problem..

Firstly, I defined the input to the controller as a `string[]`, which is incorrect. It's supposed to be a `List<string>`.

Secondly, I changed the `$.post` to `$.ajax`, this is what I ended up with (ignore the change of variable name, items to itemIds):

```
 $("#SaveButton").click(function () {

    var order = $("#attributeList ul").sortable('toArray');

    alert(order);

    $.ajax({
        data: { itemIds: order },
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true
    });
});
```

Hope this is usefull to someone else!

Answer (score 2):

Your variable "items" is out of scope for the $.post. declare the variable outside of .sortable()

```
            var items; // <-- declare the variable here.

            $("#attributeList ul").sortable({
                opacity: 0.6,
                cursor: 'move',
                update: function () {
                    items = $(this).sortable('toArray');
                    alert(items);
                }
            });

            $('submit').click(function () {

                $.post({
                    url: '/Profile/ArrangeCategories',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { items: items }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, I also realised I wasn't using the right click-event.. Unfortunately it still doesn't solve my problem, I'll edit the question...